# $location.path() is not working in scroll binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

```
 angular.module('example').service('myService', function
 myService($rootScope,$route,$http,$location) {                          
    $("#mainwindowscroll").on('scroll', function (e) {
          $location.path('/about');
    });
 });
```

Comment: what is $location value ???

Comment: $location.path = 'about' ????

Comment: You should create a directive to perform this kind of action. If you are coming from jQuery, you can read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Comment: @C-linkNepal angular guy will know that what is $location .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first reason it doesn't work is - jquery is not part of angular digest mechanism.
To make it work you should apply the location change:

```
$rootScope.$apply(function() {
    $location.path('/about');
});
```

Also, make sure the location (/about) is defined in your app module. Otherwise you can use

```
$window.location('about')
```

to navigate to a complete different path (don't forget injecting $window of course).

Comment: thanks. location (/about) is defined in my app module.  I tried `$rootScope.$apply(function() {
    $location.path('/about');
}); ` that solve the issue thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have configured the routing for the navigation url '/about'?